# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

Tags: gradle, dependencies, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am getting the following exception when running swagger2. I read online that this is usually due to referencing multiple different versions of the same jar.  However, I only found one version of org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3 in my gradle jar folder.  I also ran gradlew dependencies and found there is only one version of org.ow2.asm:asm: referenced.

What else could cause this error?

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with me, I run a android unit test and get this error too. In my case, I add this dependency in app build.gradle:

```
implementation ('org.ow2.asm:asm:9.2')
```

and then may be you also need to add:

```
implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  I actually had a libs folder that had another version of asm*..., damn it :-)!

It is working now. Thanks!