# Incompatible Class Change Error - org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser for Web Project

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, soap, servlet-3.0

I am creating a Soap Web Project in intellij, when i try to run the following project [Project Code](https://github.com/VijayIndia/SoapProject) in Jetty Runner plugin, i am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:935)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.lambda$parseJar$0(AnnotationParser.java:878)
    at java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:2897)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You can use this as an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936381/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-class-org-objectweb-asm-tree-classnode-h

Comment: Can please specify the jetty version and JDK version you're using to run you're using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Volkan Albayrak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2445028/volkan-albayrak) wrote it's a problem with different ASM versions.

Inspecting the project dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree` reveals that dependency `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-http:jar:2.5.9` brings in an ASM compile time dependency.

```
[INFO] \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-http:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.jra:jra:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]       +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]       +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile <-- this one is the problem
[INFO]       \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.5.9:compile
```

The IntelliJ plugin `IDEA Jetty Runner` (version 1.3.1) itself depends on the Eclipse [jetty runner](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-runner). And this `jetty-runner-9.4.14.v20181114.jar` contains ASM 7.0.

You need to exclude the dependency `asm:asm:jar:3.3.1` from your maven project.

in the `pom.xml` amend

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.9</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally the result of two mildly different versions of the same dependency on the classpath.

To resolve these, try launching the VM with -verbose as an argument and look at the classes that were being loaded when the exception occurs. You should see some information help you. For instance, having multiple copies of the same dependency and versions you never expected.

Resolving duplicate jars with Maven is best done with a combination of the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/) under Maven or SBT's [Dependency Graph Plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph).